# Whoever/Whatever... + Relative pronoun + Clause?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-choice, relative-pronouns, sentence-choice

From time to time, I see this type of sentence:

> Whatever/However/Whoever... + Clause
>
> Whoever wrote this should win a prize.

But aren't we supposed to put the relative pronoun *that* (or other relative pronoun) here?

> Whatever/However/Whoever... + that + clause
>
> Whoever *that* wrote this should win a prize.

I think that I hear both types of sentences, too, but I don't know whether:

> Only one of which is correct

or

> Both are correct, but there's a rule for their usage.

I'll put some sentences here bellow as examples:

> Choose whatever type of chocolate you'd like.
>
> > Choose whatever type of chocolate **that** you'd like

> Tell me whichever time suits you best to speak of this issue.
>
> Tell me whichever time **that** suits you best to speak of this issue.

> Give this gift to whomever worked hardest in your point of view.
>
> Give this gift to whomever **that/who** worked the hardest in your point of view

Comment: What makes you think that we are supposed to insert the relative pronoun?

Comment: Saying "to whomever who worked hardest" is not good, and "whichever time " is better as "what time".

Comment: @legatrix In my native tongue, we insert the relative pronoun. Also, I've heard these two types of sentence, so that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @WeatherVane so you believe it'd be better to say "To whomever worked the hardest"? Or, in a much informal tone "to whoever worked the hardest"?

Comment: Yes, and I don't remember hearing anyone say 'whomever'.

Comment: @JasonO'Neil I believe you'd hear "to whomever" no more than 1% of the time in speaking, and see it no more than 25% of the time in reading. Some languages do indeed insert a relative pronoun in this kind of structure; English does not. It just depends on the language.

Comment: @JasonO'Neil what is your native language? I might be able to help you out by doing a comparison.

Comment: @legatrix Now I understand it, thank you. It is very nice of you to ask for my native language so that you could give me a clearer answer, but your second-to-last comment has already given me a clearer picture about the subject. But I really appreciate your kindness nevertheless.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the answer! It really helped clearing  up some misconceptions of mine.